# Undefined variable: __ROOT__ PHP 7?

Tags: php

Install new PHP 7.01.

And have some errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: __ROOT__ in C:\web\index.php on line 60

require_once($__ROOT__.'/base/DBMS.php'); // - line 70
```

Comment: It appears that `$__ROOT__` is undefined in C:\web\index.php. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$__ROOT__
```

seem's to be your document root (writed as a "magic constant" variable..
and visibly, the transition to php7 broke... :)

often it's defined by using real php [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) like :

For PHP >= 5.3.0 try

```
__DIR__
```

For PHP < 5.3.0 try

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```